# Get first two HTML elements of a parsed Markdown file in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, substring, markdown

Assuming I have a Markdown file that gets parsed on the fly and returns this or similar output:

```
<h1>hello</h1><p>sometext</p><img src="image.jpg"/><ul><li>one</li>two</li></ul>
```

and I would like to return the `h1` and first `p` tag in this example. Do you think it is possible in a reliable way?
I simply want to get the substring of a Markdown parsed string with the first two elements (they could be also two different elements than `h1` and `p`)

Comment: The reliable way would be to use a DOM api. Which DOM apis are available will depend on the JS environment you are running in. A Node.js answer and a Browser answer would be different.

Comment: @Quentin Thanks for pointing it out, I meant in Node

Answer (score 0):

Use a DOM library such as cheerio, then you can convert the string to the DOM and extract the bits which interest you from it.

```
const cheerio = require('cheerio');
const html = `<h1>hello</h1><p>sometext</p><img src="image.jpg"/><ul><li>one</li>two</li></ul>`;
const $ = cheerio.load(html);
const p = $('<div />').append(
        $('p').first().clone()
).html();
const  h1= $('<div />').append(
        $('h1').first().clone()
).html();

process.stdout.write(h1);
process.stdout.write(p);
```

Comment: I don't know if the first two elements will be a `h1` and/or a `p` it could be certainly a different elements too

Comment: @supersize — You asked how to get the h1 and first p. If you want different elements, then change the selector logic to get the ones you want.

Comment: it should dynamically load the first two elements without know what they could be

Answer (score 0):

So in essence, what you want to do is scrape the web. *In this case the output from parsed markdown*

The easiest and the most familiar way would be to use [Cheerio](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio) library.

```
const cheerio = require('cheerio');
const $ = cheerio.load('<h1>hello</h1><p>sometext</p><img src="image.jpg"/><ul><li>one</li>two</li></ul>');

const h1 = $('h1');
const p = $('p');
```

It uses Jquery style syntax. But remember, cheerio is only used for static dom.

Comment: It doesn't include the content like this?

Comment: I just gave you the starting solution for your question, @Quentin's solution is more general and complete. Do try to go to the link I provided and perform R&D on your own.